# Match words in word-list and count occurrences

Tags: bash, list, sed, awk, grep

So I have a general text file with some writing in it, it really ranges randomly, but I also have a wordlist that I want to compare it with and count the occurrences of each word that appears in the text file that is on the word list.

For example my word list can be comprised of this:

```
good
bad 
cupid
banana
apple
```

Then I want to compare each of these individual words with my text file which may be like this:

`Sometimes I travel to the good places that are good, and never the bad places that are bad. For example I want to visit the heavens and meet a cupid eating an apple. Perhaps I will see mythological creatures eating other fruits like apples, bananas, and other good fruits.`

I wish my output to generate how many times each occurrence of the listed words happen. I have a way to do this is `awk` and a `for-loop` but I really wish to avoid the `for-loop` since it will take forever since my real words list is about 10000 words long.

So in this case my output should be (I think) `9` since it counts total occurrences of a word on that list.

By the way, the paragraph was totally random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any bigger text I would definitely use this:

```
perl -nE'BEGIN{open my$fh,"<",shift;my@a=map lc,map/(\w+)/g,<$fh>;@h{@a}=(0)x@a;close$fh}exists$h{$_}and$h{$_}++for map lc,/(\w+)/g}{for(keys%h){say"$_: $h{$_}";$s+=$h{$_}}say"Total: $s"' word.list input.txt
```

Comment: is there a way to add the totals of the number together?

Comment: I used grep and awk to add all the numbers together...I was asking if you could achieve it with the perl command in a one liner. I currently have this: `perl -nE'BEGIN{open my$fh,"<",shift;my@a=<$fh>;chomp@a;@h{@a}=(0)x@a;close$fh}exists$h{$_}and$h{$_}++for/(\w+)/g}{say"$_: $h{$_}"for keys%h' word1.list word2.list | grep -o '[0-9]*' | awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }' > temp.txt`

Comment: also is there a way to ignore casing with your code? so like caps and a combination of cases don't matter?

Answer (score 3):

For small to medium size texts you could use `grep` in combination with `wc`:

```
cat <<EOF > word.list
good
bad 
cupid
banana
apple
EOF

cat <<EOF > input.txt
Sometimes I travel to the good places that are good, and never the bad places that are bad. For example I want to visit the heavens and meet a cupid eating an apple. Perhaps I will see mythological creatures eating other fruits like apples, bananas, and other good fruits.
EOF

while read search ; do
    echo "$search: $(grep -o $search input.txt | wc -l)" 
done < word.list | awk '{total += $2; print}END{printf "total: %s\n", total}'
```

Output:

```
good: 3
bad: 2
cupid: 1
banan: 1
apple: 2
total: 9
```

Comment: umm my wordlist is in a text file..will i have to convert the .txt to a .list file?

Comment: no :) just use the file name of your word file. `word.list` and `input.txt` are just examples

Comment: i just realized that was a dumb question haha! thanks so much! I'm going to test my text files, I have around 1000 text files to compare with the wordlist and around 10000 words in each wordlist...this was going to be slow to begin with, but I just wanted to make it more efficient. Thanks so much!

Comment: is there a way to total the numbers in the output?

Comment: The solution I've suggested isn't the fastest too. It can be improved using awk.

Comment: hehe :) as I said there might be faster solutions, but it should work well in most cases. You must also note that the solution will find `bad` for example in `badest`. So it is not working fully correct

Answer (score 2):

An Awk solution:

```
awk -f cnt.awk words.txt input.txt
```

where `cnt.awk` is:

```
FNR==NR {
    word[$1]=0
    next
}
{
    str=str $0 RS
}
END{
    for (i in word) {
        stri=str
        while(match(stri,i)) {
           stri=substr(stri,RSTART+RLENGTH)
           word[i]++
        }
    }
    for (i in word)
        print i, word[i]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**IF** you don't need the detailed report, then this is a faster version of @hek2mgl's answer:

```
while read word; do
    grep -o $word input.txt
done < words.txt | wc -l
```

If you do need the detailed report, here's another version:

```
while read word; do
    grep -o "$word" input.txt
done < words.txt | sort | uniq -c | awk '{ total += $1; print } END { print "total:", total }'
```

Finally, if you want to match full words, then you need a more strict pattern in `grep`:

```
while read word; do
    grep -o "\<$word\>" input.txt
done < words.txt | sort | uniq -c | awk '{ total += $1; print } END { print "total:", total }'
```

However, this way the pattern `banana` will not match `bananas` in the text. If you want `banana` to match `bananas`, you could make the pattern match word beginnings like this:

```
while read word; do
    grep -o "\<$word" input.txt
done < words.txt | sort | uniq -c | awk '{ total += $1; print } END { print "total:", total }'
```

I'm not sure if it will be faster if we call `grep` with multiple words at the same time:

```
paste -d'|' - - - < words.txt | sed -e 's/ //g' -e 's/\|*$//' | while read words; do
    grep -oE "\<($words)\>" input.txt
done
```

This will `grep` for 3 words at a time. You can try adding more `-` for `paste` to match more words at once, for example:

```
paste -d'|' - - - - - - - - - - < words.txt | ...
```

In any case, I'd like to know which solution will be the fastest, this or the `awk` solution by @HakonHægland

Comment: Hi :) How does it output a detailed report for every word in word list?

Comment: You're right, it doesn't. But does he need the detailed report?

Comment: Yeah it seems so. I see a big problem with my answer: It will match `bad` for example, even when the word is `badest`. It is actually not matches whole words, it matches pattern

Comment: I noticed, I'm fixing it ;-)

Comment: Looks good. What does `\< \>` mean? (maybe stupid question but I don't know)

Comment: `\<` is pattern for start of word, and `\>` for end of word ;-)

Comment: Dunno. On the other hand, `-o` doesn't work in Solaris, so all this is already not very portable. So the `awk` solution is probably the best.

Comment: Yeah would be interesting